# Remove a created Div

Tags: javascript, append, clone, getelementbyid, removechild

I am trying to make my code delete a div newly using a function.

The JavaScript can add new a new div without any issues. However the remove button isn't responsive.

How do I make my JavaScript remove the div.

Script:

```js
 <script async> // hidden answer for adding new answers jacascript code
      function clonebutton1 (counter){
       counter = counter +1;
       var div = document.createElement('div');
       div.className = 'container-fluid form-group col-lg-6';
       div.innerHTML ='<label>Answer:\
   <span id="ansNo">'+counter+'</span>\
   </label> \
   <input class="form-control" id="AnswerClone" name="quizAnswerNew[]" placeholder="Please Enter An Answer......" type="text" value="">\
   <div class="form-group">\
    <label for="select1">Pick a Score For The Answer:</label> \
    <select class="score-choice" id="selectClone" name="selectNew">\
    <option selected value="0">0</option><option value="5">5</option><option>10</option><option>15</option><option>20</option>\
    </select>\
   </div>\
   <div style="margin-bottom:20px;">\
    <label class="btn-bs-file btn btn-sm btn-primary">Add Picture <input name="answerFileNew" type="file"></label>\
   </div><input class="btn btn-primary removeAnswer" id="removeAnswer" type="button" value="Remove Answer">\
  </div>';
 
   document.getElementById('AnswerSectionNew').appendChild(div);
                   div.on("click", function() {// this function removes the parent of the removeAnswer button that is clicked
         $(this).parent().remove();
       });
   document.getElementById('addAnotherAnswer').setAttribute("onClick","clonebutton1("+counter+")");
   };
     
     
       
 </script>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are binding the function to the `click` event of the button but maybe that div it's not yet created. So you should rebind the click event each time you create the div with the button.

Another option would be use the onclick attribute on the button when creating (this is when you write the html) to execute the JavaScript function.